# Does forge.facebook.authorize open native facebook app?

Tags: facebook, trigger.io

I've been looking at forge's new APIs (they look awesome)!

For the [forge-facebook-API](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/facebook.html), I was wondering: does it actually open the native facebook app on the phone to ask for permissions?

I've done the ChildBrowser internet login to facebook before, and users are almost never already logged into Facebook Web.  It's annoying to make them type in their facebook credentials on the web to use my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. This is called SSO. From Forge's docs:

```
'within each of those sections SSO should also be enabled.'
```

But facebook has made all this automatic, so its auto enabled (You can't disable it, afaik). So hence yes is the answer to your question.

Comment: If the Facebook app is not installed we fall back to web authn/authz, and also work with the iOS 6 Accounts framework.